# `List` not rendering in `MenuBarExtra`

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit, swiftui-list

I'm new to Swift, SwiftUI, and AppKit.

I'm creating a menu bar app for macOS using `MenuBarExtra`.

Why are the `List`s not rendering in `MenuPanel`?

```swift
// MacOSSoundUtilityApp.swift

import SwiftUI

@main
struct MacOSSoundUtilityApp: App {    
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("Utility App", systemImage: "hammer") {
            MenuPanel()
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.menu)
    }
}
```

```swift
// MenuPanel.swift

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SomeApp: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let id = UUID()
}

struct MenuPanel: View {
    var applications = [SomeApp(name: "app 1"), SomeApp(name: "app 2"), SomeApp(name: "app 3")]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Utility App")
                .font(.title)
            List {
                Text("option1")
                Text("option2")
                Text("option3")
            }
            List (applications) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `window` menu bar extra style instead of the `menu` menu bar extra style. The documentation describes the `window` style  as "The styling and layout of controls is similar to that when contained in a normal window, compared to the menu-like layout that the menu style provides."  (via https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubarextrastyle/window)

So it would allow rendering of your custom list, vs the `menu` style has similar restrictions on what